# Print the file name after summing a column in the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

I'm using bash and I have a directory that has a bunch of files that look like this:

```
$ cat myFile.txt
 128 foo bar baz
4891 cat dog
  36 fish cat
 942 potato pants
 ...
```

I would like to create an output like this:

```
myFile.txt 5194
another.txt 4920
...
```

and so on.  I know how to sum the files using:

```
cat myFile.txt | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

But I don't know how to re-print the file name.  In particular, I want to be able to do it without knowing the filename in advance, like this:

```
cat *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ - | bc | ... something here?
```

Comment: Not sure how you can expect `5194` from myFile.txt. The total of column 1 is `5997`

Comment: @hek2mgl Easy:  I gave an example with randomly typed numbers to indicate format, rather than specific value, since I already said verbally that I wanted a sum.

Comment: Imo the expected output should match the example input.

Comment: @hek2mgl Sure, why not -- I fixed it for those with more delicate sensibilities =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `for` loop:

```
for f in *.txt: do
   awk '{sum+=$1} END{print FILENAME, sum}' "$f"
done
```

`print` statement in `awk` will print both input filename and sum.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I didn't know about FILENAME in awk, but I suspected there was *something* like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'function p(){if(pf)print pf,s;s=0}FNR==1{p()}{s+=$1;pf=FILENAME}END{p()}' *.txt
```

Better Readable

```
awk '
       function p(){
           if(pf)print pf,s;
           s=0
       }
       FNR==1{
               p()
       }
       {
           s+=$1;
           pf=FILENAME
       }
       END{
            p()
       }
    ' *.txt
```

***Test Results***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ ls *.txt
f1.txt  f2.txt

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f1.txt 
1
2
3

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f2.txt 
128
1
2

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk 'function p(){if(pf)print pf,s;s=0}FNR==1{p()}{s+=$1; pf=FILENAME}END{p()}' *.txt
f1.txt 6
f2.txt 131
```

Comment: or even this `awk 'function p(){print pf,s;s=0}NR!=FNR && FNR==1{p()}{s+=$1; pf=FILENAME}END{p()}' *.txt`